# Get More Information when Big Query load fails with CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to load a table into Big Query from a CSV file but it is failing with

> CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Row: 1 errors: 1
>   JobId nnnnn

When I click on the job status in the Big Query console. there is no more information.

How can I find more specific info on the error?

Answer (score 0):

To get more info on the errors try this from the CLI:

`>bq show -j  <jobid>`

It prints the status and/or detailed error information.

To list all the jobids:

`bq ls -j`

Comment: Using `bq --format=prettyjson show -j job_id` will show the complete job information as JSON, which can be helpful.